# Можно ли удалить jar из локального репозитария без pom.xml?

Tags: java, maven

Я установил jar в локальный репозитарий с помощью команды:

```
  mvn install:install-file -Dfile=aaa.jar -DgroupId=bbb -DartifactId=ccc -Dversion=1.0 -Dpackaging=jar
```

Теперь хочу удалить его. Пробую:

`mvn dependency:purge-local-repository -DmanualInclude=bbb-ccc`

Получаю ошибку:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:purge-local-repository (default-cli): Goal requires a project to execute but there is no POM in this directory (...). Please verify you invoked Maven from the correct directory. -> [Help 1]`

Теперь создаю файлик `pom.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project>
  <groupId>bbb</groupId>
  <artifactId>ccc</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <properties> 
    <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
    <artifactId>${project.artifactId}</artifactId>
    <version>${project.version}</version>
    <packaging>${project.packaging}</packaging>
    <file>aaa.jar</file>
  </properties>     
</project>
```

Сейчас уже без проблема удаляется. А можно всё-таки удалить jar без этого `pom.xml`?

Использую 3.2.5 (windows x64).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я пропустил, что для `purge-local-repository` стояло требование существующего проекта и соответственно pom.xml.

Другой момент, что [manualInclude](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/purge-local-repository-mojo.html#manualInclude) должен работать и без `pom.xml`. Но не работал. Как понимаю - уже [пофиксили](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MDEP-537).

Answer (score 2):

Конечно, можно просто удалить директорию с артифактами из локального репозитория. Для `linux` это будет так:

```
rm -R {user_directory}/.m2/repository/{groupId}/{artifactId}/{version}
```

Comment: Да, понимаю. Просто хотелось удалить, как и добавлят через mvn. Но видимо так нельзя (оставлю в стороне вопрос, а зачем вообще удалять).

Comment: единственное преимущество простого как пробка кэша Мавена, что можно туда пойти и стереть то, что нужно. Так что да, именно так.

Comment: Была всё таки бага, сейчас в посте ниже отпишу.